# Why does PyArg_ParseTuple always return false?

Tags: python, c++, python-extensions

My `PyFLoat_ParseTuple` call always return false, with correct call from python side.

I am working on wrapping my C++ for Python and using python extension.
I had a successful project, and generating the current one based on that.
I always had a crash in my python run, and during the investigation I reduced my code to the following minim code to repeat it.

If I change both C++/Python side to non-arg call, it works as expected.
But the "Parse error" is always printed when I passed in args.

C++:

```cpp
static PyObject *myfunc(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    float v[6];
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ffffff", v,v+1,v+2,v+3,v+4,v+5));
    { 
                //I can alway see this prited.
        cerr<<"Parse error\n";
        return NULL;
    }
        return PyString_FromFormat("No error!\n");
}
```

Python:

```python
print func(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6)
```

Answer (score 1):

a very simple typo:

```
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ffffff", v,v+1,v+2,v+3,v+4,v+5));
```

- see the semicolon `;` at the end of `if`?